# How to use call dynamic_array right?

Tags: arrays, sas, dynamic-arrays

I have try to write a user-defined function `MinDis()` and apply it in data step, this function is used to compute the minimum distance from one point to each element of an (numeric)array. Code fllowing:

```
proc fcmp outlib = work.funcs.Math;
    function MinDis(Exp,Arr[*]);
        array dis[2] /symbols;
        call dynamic_array(dis,dim(Arr));
        do i = 1 to dim(Arr);
            dis[i] = abs((Exp - Arr[i]));
        end;
        return(min(of dis[*]));
    endsub;
quit;

option cmplib=work.funcs ; 

data MinDis;
    input LamdazLower LamdazUpper @;
    cards;
    2.50 10.0
    2.51 10.8
    2.49 9.97
    2.75 9.50
    ;
run;

data _null_;
    set ;

    array _PTN_ [14] _temporary_ (0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12);
    StdLamZLow = MinDis(LamdazLower,_PTN_);
    StdLamZUpp = MinDis(LamdazUpper,_PTN_);
    put _all_;
run;
```

It was compile rightly but gave wrong results. `StdLamZLow` just get the minimum distance from `LamdazLower` to the first two element of array `_PTN_`.

When I rewrite the dim of `dis` as 999 or something very big and get rid of `call dynamic_array` statement I would get it right. But I surely want to know why `min(of dis[*])` just take `dis` as a 2-dim array.

By the way, how can I use implied DO-loops `do over ...` to instead of explicit DO loops? I have tried several times but haven`t success yet.

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this happens cause of dynamic array. `MIN` function see just static length of dis array(2 in your case). So you should try to compute min of array without calling `MIN` function:

```
proc fcmp outlib = work.funcs.Math;
    function MinDis(Exp,Arr[*]);
        length=dim(Arr);
        array dis[2] /nosymbols;
        call dynamic_array(dis,length);
        dis[1]=abs((Exp - Arr[1]));
        min=dis[1];
        do i = 1 to length;
            dis[i] = abs((Exp - Arr[i]));
            if dis[i] < min then min=dis[i];
        end;
        return(min);
    endsub;
quit;
```

Output:

> LamdazLower=2.5 LamdazUpper=10 StdLamZLow=0 StdLamZUpp=0
>
> LamdazLower=2.51 LamdazUpper=10.8 StdLamZLow=0.01 StdLamZUpp=0.8
>
> LamdazLower=2.49 LamdazUpper=9.97 StdLamZLow=0.01 StdLamZUpp=0.03
>
> LamdazLower=2.75 LamdazUpper=9.5 StdLamZLow=0.25 StdLamZUpp=0.5

In addition about implied DO-loops([here](http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings10/158-2010.pdf) on 6th page), if i correctly understood the question:

```
data temp;
array dis dis1-dis4;
do over dis;
   dis=2;
   put _all_;
end;
run;
```

Output:

> *I*=1 dis1=2 dis2=. dis3=. dis4=. *ERROR*=0 *N*=1
>
> *I*=2 dis1=2 dis2=2 dis3=. dis4=. *ERROR*=0 *N*=1
>
> *I*=3 dis1=2 dis2=2 dis3=2 dis4=. *ERROR*=0 *N*=1
>
> *I*=4 dis1=2 dis2=2 dis3=2 dis4=2 *ERROR*=0 *N*=1

Comment: That makes sense. Could you please talk more about the usage of implied DO-loop in FCMP?

Comment: @whymath edited my answer, but it's hard to undertand what you want to know. I add code sample and output of using do over, and papers.

Comment: thanks for your detailed description, what I means is the usage of `do over` in `proc fcmp`.

Comment: @whymath oh, i didn't see anything about it. I'm not sure it's possible.

Comment: It seems implict arrays is not supported in fcmp because of the uncertainty of number of arguments. Thanks anyway.